# Is there any way to automatically download the windows update files?

Tags: windows, windows-update

From what I've seen on the Microsoft Homepage and other pages the normal way for a distributed update mechanism is to use the Windows update mechanism and deploy the updates from a central Server.

What I'm wondering though is for a more Manual way if it is possible to just download the Windows update files for a more Manual Distribution.

Thus is there a way to automatically download the files themselves? (or is the only way to search for each and every file by Hand to see if it exists downloadable)

Comment: Find your update package in [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx)

Comment: [Windows Update PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) - "The PSWindowsUpdate module allow you to manage Windows Update on your computer. Module contain set of function to check, download and install or remove update from local machine."

Answer (score 1):

**yes in this address you can find manual windows update just by search the distribution you have**

http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx

Comment: how do I know which Distribution I Need?

Comment: You must know what distro you need. Otherwise you can type this command to khow what version of windows you use. "winver"

Comment: and can I glean from that (with that command) what the next distribution I need is?

Comment: please explain more and clear
you want to install manual updates on serverside by command or you want to download the offline updates by command line